# setting in one class and getting from another class

Tags: java, android

this is really basic I know, but I just can't see what the problem is... all I want to do is set the value of a variable from one class into an "intermediary" class and retrieve it in a third class (because filterArray will get called from other classes as well, and I want them all to read the same data). But if I do:

```
b =new GetSet()
b.setBdl(extras);
JSONArray arr= getData.filterArray();
```

using

```
class GetSet {
  private Bundle params;

  public GetSet() {
    }

  public Bundle getBdl() {
    return this.params;
  }

  public void setBdl(Bundle bdl) {

    params = bdl;
  }
}
```

then in the filterArray method, if I try

```
       Bundle params = new GetSet().getBdl();
```

I get all sorts of run time errors, and if I try

```
Bundle params = GetSet.getBdl();
```

it tells me I can't make a static reference to a non-static method.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: so confused what you are trying to do? you make a new GetSet, then you say in filterArray you create a new GetSet? so confusing

Comment: erm. I'm trying to get params out of the GetSet class. But if I don't include the new keyword it tells me I can't make a static reference to a non-static method. 
I'm confused, too, if it's any consolation.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `b` to `filterArray` method.
First change `filterArray` to get one parameter of type `GetSet`:

```
public JSONArray filterArray(GetSet b)
```

Then, call it like:

```
getData.filterArray(b);
```

And inside `filterArray` just use:

```
Bundle params = b.getBdl();
```

The problem is that you create an object and sets a value, then you need to get the value from the **same** object.

When working with objects, you can create a new object of whatever class you want, set its internal value and when you access the same object from different places, the internal value will be the same (Im talking here both on `GetSet` and `getData`.

Another option is to use static value (and static getters and setters), if the value is same for all objects of the class. This usually not needed and may be used due to bad design. In your case you don't really need it, but it will work.

Comment: this is the point, though - because later, from a different method I want to be able to call the filterarray method without passing b (because b will already be set) and I want filter array just to be able to get b from the GetSet class

Comment: You can create a new `getData` object, and set `b` as internal value. Another option' if the value is same for all GetSet objects, you can use static for param (and getters and setters) but this is a very bad design.

Comment: no, it's always going to be changing, that's the thing. how do I set b as an internal value?

Comment: Did you write the getData class? so you can add b value and getters and setters to b, just like you did with `Bundle` in `GetSet` class. Then you need to make sure again to access the same object of getData from all places.

Comment: I don't know if I'm following, but this, I think is my problem... that sometimes I will be able to pass b into filterArray, but sometimes I will be relying on it having already been set. I'm still not following how to set the internal value. Sorry for being thick - I'm quite new to java.

Answer (score 0):

The errors are because you are using it in a wrong way

look at your signature of getBdl its a public `Bundle` method its a non static method so can't be accessed by the classname.

it should be accessed through the bean object that is b,

second error is also related,

you wrote/set the property of the bean with the object b but when you access it , you are again creating a new GetSet().getBdl so it says `Null pointer exception`

so do like this

GetSet b=new GetSet();
b.setBdl(bundle object);

so now b contains the value
pass the b...

so get the bundle through b,,if you need to access it from another class pass b into its constructor and get it their

SomeClass class=new SomeClass(b);
now in that class you can get the bundle via b

hope it all helps you.

Comment: but does b still exist if that method has finished and I am now calling it from a different class (I guess I should just test it and see)?

Comment: see The even if that method has finished you passed the bean object to someother class constructor so b lives and you can be able to access the methods of it ...